# Increase number X by 1, if number increases by 2

Tags: python, numbers

How could I make the below code shorter?

```
if size == "6":
        element = '#pdp__select-size > li:nth-child(1) > button'

if size == "8":
        element = '#pdp__select-size > li:nth-child(2) > button'

if size == "10":
        element = '#pdp__select-size > li:nth-child(3) > button'

if size == "12":
        element = '#pdp__select-size > li:nth-child(4) > button'

if size == "14":
        element = '#pdp__select-size > li:nth-child(5) > button'

if size == "16":
        element = '#pdp__select-size > li:nth-child(6) > button'

if size == "18":
        element = '#pdp__select-size > li:nth-child(7) > button'
```

Basically, every time the size increases by 2 (from 6 > 8) etc ... I want the number in the element to increase by 1 (from 1>2) etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert `size` to an integer and perform a little arithmetic to get the value that goes in `nth()`.

```
size_int = int(size)
if size_int % 2 == 0 and 6 <= size_int <= 18:
    # size is even
    nth = size_int//2 - 2
    element = f"#pdp__select-size > li:nth-child({nth}) > button"
```

Comment: `nth = size_int/2 - 2` is probably a bit more simple ;)

Comment: `nth = size_int//2 - 2` to keep integer type then

Comment: Maybe, but I wanted to relate it to the `18` in results, and 9 == 18/2